# Cakephp 4 with Friends Of Cake cakepdf not downloading file in Firefox

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

CakePdf plugin was working with 'download' => true, then lost that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Spent way to much time trouble shooting this.  Only to figure out a Firefox upgrade re-set the application settings on how to handle PDF files.  Changed back to Always Ask vs Open in browser.  I knew this, but I assumed something else with the issue.